# angularJS bootstrap navigation bar issue

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wrote below to get navigation bar. It doesn't give me any errors. But output is not what I expected. below is my html code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-inverse-main" role="navigation" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" >
<!--<nav class="nav navbar-default" role="navigation">-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centerd">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#/home">List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/create">Add</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Can some one help me identify what is missing. This is using angularJS bootstrap.

and what I get when I run is in below picture.

Result
[image]

I tried to identify what went wrong. Someone please have a look. This is my first time trying angular bootstrap.

Comment: Did you put the CSS file into the HTML file?

Comment: Hey I had installed bower components so bootstrap css jquery was already there. it was in my index.php file. then I re added angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script> and netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
then it worked. I didnt know I have to add them again when i already had ui bootstrap for angular.